# Configurable product image resolution issue

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, category-listing, configurable-swatches

I'm having an issue with configurable product swatch on my category view page (in grid mode).

We are using image in 420px in our category page but the image that are automatically switch with the swatches sources are in 210x.

[image]

All the product images source are coming from the `getProductImageFallbacks()` function from the configurable swatch Core (`Block/Catalog/Media/Js/Abstract.php`)

But i am stuck on how to change the resolution there. Really looking for any advice on where to go from there.

Please note that i sadly cannot go the easy way with a css fix due to image quality.

Comment: Hey, I'm facing the same issue but couldn't find any solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was basically overthinking it.

The solution is dead simple: 
 1. Go to Configuration > Catalog > Product Image
 2. Change the product Small Image Width to the width you need
 3. Clear cache 
 4. Voila

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it changes width and height with same value that i give in there. But I need to change height as well like 245x344 px

Comment: @IbnulHasan I'm not sure I understand your issue. The height will be relative to the width you define for the small image. You can also use a specific small image in the product image section. Hope it helps !

Comment: thanks for your reply. Actually when I'm on category list page the image size of products are fine (245 x 344px) But clicking on color box to see other color image, it's loading 245 x 245 px size image, I've configured in Catalog page small image width 245px. I've also uploaded 245 x 344 px size image and selected that as Small image but still it's not working. Please help me finding the issue. 
Note that I'm using a custom magento theme from themeforest and I contacted them and they said it's Magento issue not theme.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it depends on the theme. For my case as I am using a custom theme from themeforest.net and the product images in category product list page  are vertically rectangle like 245x344px dimension. But when on swatch box click the product image is loading through jQuery, it's getting the size from configuration settings and loading square image of that size like 245x245px which is wrong for me.

**So I've just removed width from configuration settings and now it's loading the base image and it's rectangle now.** It's just for my solution. 
Hope it'll help to someone else.
Thanks